# Save an empty string to the database in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am working with a legacy database that has a bit of a design quirk. There is a column set to `NOT NULL` but that has a default value of "" (empty string). This is causing me issues when attempting to save to this column. Rails is automatically turning any attribute that is empty to nil.

```
my_class = MyClass.new
my_class.variable = ''
```

this will evaluate to nil, I understand the Rails convention is to send nil, it makes sense, but in this case I have to send the empty string for data integrity. How can I force ActiveRecord to actually save the empty string to the database?

Edit:

```
# Console
1.9.3-p484 :002 > my_class = TestClass.new
=> nil
1.9.3-p484 :003 > my_class.name = 'hello'
=> "hello"
1.9.3-p484 :004 > my_class.name
=> "hello"
1.9.3-p484 :005 > my_class.name = ''
=> ""
1.9.3-p484 :006 > my_class.name
=> nil
```

The attribute's getter will always return nil even when I set it as an empty string.

Comment: AFAIK there's no rails convention to save "" as null, in string or text format fields at least.

Comment: I'm getting string for last line. not nil....

Comment: That is what I would expect but this is maddening. I'm using rails 3.2.13 and every attribute on the model behaves this way. I have a Rails 4 project that does not do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the datatype of the column?  If it's string then it should let you save the empty string.  if it's (eg) integer it will save "" as "null".

Comment: It is a string. Oddly, if I set the variable to '' and then in query the variable, it just tells me it's nil. Even in the console I can see it happen.

Answer (score 0):

Use `before_save` callback to replace `nil` into `''`.